# Prove the lines from the corners of a triangle to the midpoint of opposite sides bisect each other.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Let ABC be a triangle. Prove that the lines from the corners to the midpoint of opposite sides intersect each other.
I tried this, i got stuck. My approach to the question:

[image]

Comment: That's not true.  The three lines meet at a single point that divides each of of them in the ratio $1:2$.  The smaller segment is closer to base while the larger segment is closer to the vertex.

Comment: You probably mean “intersect each other”, not “bisect each other”.

Comment: I changed “bisect” to “intersect”. If that’s not what you meant, @Maranatha, please change it back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

First, think about the point $P = \tfrac13(A+B+C)$. This is a nice simple symmetric expression, so there’s a good chance that this is the common intersection point you’re seeking.

A line that joins a vertex of a triangle to the mid-point of the opposite side is called a **median**. If you can show that the point $P$ lies on each of the medians, then you’re done.

Think about the median that joins $A$ to the mid-point of $BC$. The mid-point of $BC$ is $M= \tfrac12(B+C)$. Points that lie on the median $AM$ are of the form $A + k(M-A)$, for some $k$. The number $k$ tells you what fraction of $AM$ you have to traverse to get to the point. Can you find a value of $k$ that gives you $A + k(M-A) = P$?

Now do the same trick on the other two medians, and you’re done.